# Python, Flask и PiCamera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Имеется PiCamera с RPi. Пытаюсь написать Python код для управления камерой с помощью веб. В данный момент мой код выглядит вот так

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Test version
'''

from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime
import io
import time
import picamera
import logging
import sys
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s '
                    + '[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s:%(funcName)s()] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

@app.route("/start", methods=['POST'])
def start_capture():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(300)


@app.route("/stop", method=['POST'])
def stop_capture():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.stop_preview()


@app.route("/screenshot", methods=['POST'])
def screenshot():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.capture('foo.jpg', use_video_port=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='192.168.0.198', port='8080')
```

Первое что не работает правильно - если я отправляю `POST` запрос к примеру на `192.168.192:8080/start`, запрос отправляется бесконечно. 
Далее есть после старта, отправить запрос на стоп, ничего не происходит. Где я что, сделал не правильно? Есть ли способ, каким-то образом записать все в одну функцию, но при это вызывать разным запросом определенные части функции?

Comment: Оффтоп: `pass` в конце непустых блоков не нужен

Comment: 1 — «`/start`, запрос отправляется бесконечно» — ну так там и стоит sleep на 300 секунд, всё правильно :)

Comment: @andreymal исправил, спасибо. Но пока это ничего не решило. Я пытался ставить sleep(), но ничего нового.

Comment: 2 — родной сервер Flask по умолчанию однопоточен и принимает запросы последовательно, и пока `/start` всё ещё спит 300 секунд, он не может принять запрос `/stop` :) (Если я угадал, вынесу в ответ) (хотя ещё есть подозрения, что вот так, как здесь, использовать камеру вообще нельзя, но с `picamera` работать не доводилось)

Comment: @andreymal поставил на time.sleep() - теперь скрипт вообще не запускается. А вот есть `@app.route` - использовать два раза, и в одном `def` использовать разный вызов, как это сделать и будет ли работать?

Comment: Так надо sleep убрать совсем

Comment: @andreymal есть убрать `sleep`, такая же фигня, ничего не работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробую угадать ответ по документации `picamera`. Согласно ей, при входе в `with`-блок камера включается, а при выходе выключается, то есть получается:

```
@app.route("/start", methods=['POST'])
def start_capture():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:  # Включили камеру
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
        camera.start_preview()
    # with закончился — выключили камеру
```

Отсюда вывод: надо как-то держать камеру постоянно включенной независимо от http-запросов. Простейший способ — вынести `camera` в глобальную переменную, где она и будет лежать включенная независимо от http-запросов:

```
from threading import Lock
import picamera

camera = None  # Сразу после запуска камера выключена

camlock = Lock()  # Блокировка нужна, чтобы нельзя было
# лезть в камеру из нескольких запросов одновременно

# ... app = Flask(__name__) logging всё такое скопировать сюда из вопроса #


@app.route("/start", methods=['POST'])
def start_capture():
    global camera
    with camlock:
        if camera:
            return 'already started'
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
    return 'ok'


@app.route("/stop", methods=['POST'])
def stop_capture():
    global camera
    with camlock:
        if not camera:
            return 'already stopped'
        camera.close()
        camera = None
    return 'ok'


@app.route("/screenshot", methods=['POST'])
def screenshot():
    # Переменную не меняем — global необязателен
    with camlock:
        if not camera:
            return 'camera is not started'
        camera.capture('foo.jpg', use_video_port=True)
    return 'saved to foo.jpg'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app.run(host='192.168.0.198', port='8080')
    finally:
        # При завершении работы http-сервера камеру стоит выключить
        with camlock:
            if camera:
                camera.close()
```

Raspberry Pi не имею и проверить работоспособность кода не могу, но вроде не должен был накосячить.

(Замечание 1: глобальные переменные — довольно опасная штука, и при увеличении сложности проекта от них можно начать получать множество проблем, когда они начнут меняться непредсказуемо и всё такое.)

(Замечание 2: возможно, более хорошим решением будет запуск второго потока, который и будет обслуживать камеру (без глобальной переменной) и принимать сообщения-команды от http-сервера из первого потока вместо непосредственного доступа к камере, но это увеличивает сложность и не факт что целесообразно в данном случае.)

Comment: Хм, а если приспичит использовать `camera.start_recording`, то придётся-таки следовать замечанию 2

Comment: Пример приведенный выше не работает. Питон запускается и сразу закрывается.

Comment: Он должен писать какие-нибудь ошибки

Comment: Пишет следующее - http://pastebin.com/NRpm7m0a

Comment: В вопросе опечатка, вместо `method=` надо `methods=`, а я слепо скопировал :)

Comment: Да именно этого не хватало ) теперь добавил в блок `start` - `camera.preview_start()`, но почему-то не вижу никакого `preview`

Comment: По поводу `preview_start` ничего сказать не могу, кроме того, что через http его увидеть никак нельзя (он на это не рассчитан), а если нужно, то это уже видеостриминг и все ещё сложнее и выходит за рамки вопроса :)

Comment: не важно, я уже нашел решение почему оно не стартовала.