# Python - получение значений из конфиг файла

Tags: python

Пытаюсь заставить RPi и PiCamera сгенирировать файл и папку для записи кажого видео в отдельную папку.

Для начала был взят код [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490138/python-flask-%D0%B8-picamera/490147#490147)

Далее, я создал конфиг файл у которого есть значение `directory = './recordings'`

также немного переписал код записи

```
@app.route("/start_record", methods=['POST'])
def start_capture():
    global camera
    with camlock:
        if camera:
            return 'already started'
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
        camera.start_preview()
        now = get_timestamp()
        recording_name = 'recording-%i' % (now)
        recording_dir = '%s/%s' % (CONFIG['capture']['directory'], recording_name)
        mkdir(CONFIG['capture']['directory'])
        os.mkdir(recording_dir)
        camera.start_recording('test.h264')
    return 'recording'
```

Как мне заставить python, получить `directory` из конфиг файла, а также заменить `test.h264` на `recording_name.h264`

Comment: 2-й вопрос: `camera.start_recording('{}.h264'.format(recording_name))`

Comment: а зачем .format?

Comment: 1-й: а) Открыть файл, б) найти строку `recording = ...` в) прочитать эту строку.

Comment: чтобы получилось recording_name.h264, если я правиляно понял вопрос. Вариант: `'%s.h264' % recording_name`

Comment: @andy.37 ну теоретически я знаю как. а вот как это преобразовать в код, не получается.

Comment: @andy.37 `recordin_name` - генерируется само, так что скорее ваш второй вариант правильнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
camera.start_recording('{}.h264'.format(recording_name))
# вариант: camera.start_recording('%s.h264' % recording_name)
```

Варианты **совершенно** эквивалентны (не уверен, работает ли 2-й в 3-ем питоне)

2)

```
with open('path/to/config_file', 'r') as f:
   for l in f:
      if l.startswith('recording = '):
          recording = l.split(' = ')[1]
```

3) Правильно будет написать:

```
camera.start_recording(os.path.join(CONFIG['capture']['directory'], '{}.h264'.format(recording_name)))
```

Вы делаете директорию (2 раза причем), но пишете не в нее.

Comment: к сожалению 1. не работает, в обоих вариантах

Comment: @Insider Этого не может быть. `s = 'some_text'; print '{}.xxx'.format(s) --> some_text.xxx`. `s = 1; print '{}.xxx'.format(s) --> 1.xxx`

Comment: камера не начинает записывать как в случае с file_name.h264

Comment: а возможно проще?        `camera.start_recording(os.path.join('./record', '{}.h264'.format(recording_name)))`

Comment: @Insider, да можно, конечно. Но тогда зачем фам конфиг с recording = ...?

Comment: так как в будущем планирую, при записи в конфиг файл к примеру того же IP адреса, менять и IP адрес на самом устройстве. Вот правда как я написал, почему-то не хочет работать.

Comment: Вы, часом, не на виндах это делаете? Может слэш не тот? Да и `'./record'` - лишнее в любом случае, лучше оставить просто `'record'`

Comment: кстати,когда пытаюсь вывести     `return 'recording %s' % recording_name`
показывает ошибку 500. Не может ли все это зависеть от flask?

Comment: Нет, все делаю на Raspberry Pi

Comment: Гляньте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059937/flask-app-raises-a-500-error-with-no-exception. Сам во фласке очень не. Там похоже функция должна что-то определенное возвращать.

Comment: попробовал таким способом         `camera.start_recording('record_{timestamp:%H-%M-%S-%f}.h264')`
в результате выводит мне файл `record_{timestamp:%H-%M-%S-%f}.h264`