# PyCharm - OSError: dlopen(libmmal.so, 6): image not found

Tags: python, pycharm

Установил PyCharm. Установил все необходимые пакеты для interpreter. Пытаюсь запустить из него свой код. Но получаю ошибку `OSError: dlopen(libmmal.so, 6): image not found`

вот все что импортировано

```
from flask import Flask, session, url_for, escape, request, jsonify
from simplepam import authenticate
from flask import render_template, redirect
import datetime
import time
import os
from threading import Lock
import picamera
import ConfigParser
```

сталкивался кто?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял, используется на Raspberry Pi вместе с Raspian?

Эта проблема связана со строчкой `import picamera`.

1. На *малино-линуксе* библиотека `libmmal.so` должна находиться в `/opt/vc/lib`. Проверьте (библиотеки можно взять [отсюда](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/opt/vc/lib)).
2. Затем взгляните на содержимое `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/00-vmcs.conf`. Там должно быть `/opt/vc/lib`. Если нет, то сделайте:
3. `ldconfig`, чтобы переинициализировать пути к библиотекам.

Comment: используется OS X с IDE PyCharm

Comment: @Insider зачем на OS X используется модуль `picamera` от Raspberry Pi?

Comment: я же написал, это IDE, использую его для отладки кода

Comment: @Insider Как именно вы запускаете свой код, удаленно на целевой системе? Если нет, то как вы представляете себе использование модуля `picamera`, который, во-первых, отсутствует в вашей ОС, и, во-вторых, предназначен для архитектуры **ARM**?

Comment: @Insider посмотрел, вы же спрашивали как-то о ["Python, Flask и PiCamera"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490138/python-flask-%d0%b8-picamera). Не получится так делать, как вы хотите, - заниматься отладкой ARM-модулей в x86-окружении. Вы изначально не внесли ясность в вопрос, и я думаю, он некорректен.

Comment: в IDE PiCharm можно установить picamera, собственно поэтому я и подумал, что можно заниматься и отладкойэ

Comment: PyCharm  используется как окошко для удаленного деплоймента/тестинга по sshfs/ssh/sftp/vagrant/rdp/vnc... То есть код исполняется удаленно на самой малинке. А по вашей ошибке и пробелах в описании непонятно, что и где именно происходит. Возможно, вы запускаете код локально, а не на малине. Но это я предполагаю.